# php mysql inserting file details but not the file name itself during uploading

Tags: php

I have a problem with my file upload form. The form uploads all the file details but not the file name itself. The `$file` variable is not sent with the rest of the form, this is where most of my problems reside.

```
<?php   
if(isset($_POST['submit'])=="Submit") //check whether the form was submitted
    {

        $etablissement = cleanData($_POST['etablissement']);     
        $classe = cleanData($_POST['classe']);   
        $session = cleanData($_POST['session']);     
        $matiere = cleanData($_POST['matiere']);     
        $annee_scolaire = cleanData($_POST['anescolaire']);
        //$dossier = '../../assnet/uploads/'; //chemin absolu(vers la racine assnet)
        //$fichier = basename($_FILES['epreuve']['name']);

        //$file = basename($_FILES['epreuve']['name']);

        //print "Data cleaned";  
        addData($etablissement, $classe, $session, $matiere, $annee_scolaire);   
    }    
else
    {    
        printForm();     
    }    

function checkUpload() //check whether everything is OK before uploading the file
{
    //check for an uploaded file
    if(isset($_FILES['epreuve'])){
        //Validate the type 

        $allowed_extensions = array('application/pdf','application/pdf','application/doc','application/docx','application/ppt','application/pptx');
        if(in_array($_FILES['epreuve']['type'], $allowed_extensions)){
            print "Uploading files...";

            //move the file over
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['epreuve']['tmp_name'], "../../assnet/uploads/{$_FILES['epreuve']['name']}")){
                echo "<p><em>The file has been uploaded</em></p>";

                $file = "{$_FILES['epreuve']['name']}";
                print "$file"; //the file name is normally displayed here
            } //End of move... IF
        } else{ //invalid type
            echo '<p class="error">Please upload a pdf, doc, docx, ppt or pptx document</p>';

            if($_FILES['epreuve']['error'] > 0){
                echo '<p class="error">The file could not be uploaded because : </strong>';
                //Print a message upon the error. NB: There is no error message 5

                switch($_FILES['epreuve']['error']){
                case 1:
                    print 'The file exceeds the upload_max_file_size setting in php.ini.';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    print 'The file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE setting in the HTML form';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    print 'The file was only partially uploaded';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    print 'No file was uploaded';
                    break;
                case 6:
                    print 'No temporary folder was available';
                    break;
                case 7:
                    print 'Unable to write to disk';
                    break;
                case 8: 
                    print 'File upload stopped';
                    break;
                default:
                    print 'A system error occured';
                    break;
                } //End of switch
            }//End of Error... IF

            //Delete the file if it still exists
            if(file_exists($_FILES['epreuve']['tmp_name']) && is_file($_FILES['epreuve']['tmp_name'])){
                print 'File already exists';
                unlink($_FILES['epreuve']['tmp_name']); //delete the file from the temporary folder if it still exists
            }   
            return $file; //returns the file from where it comes from
            //i.e from the addData function "[$image=checkUpload()]"

        }
    }
}

function cleanData($data){ //this fxn prevents us from sql injection
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    return $data;
}

function addData($etablissement, $classe, $session, $matiere, $annee_scolaire) //adding the data     
{    
    //print "Ready to add data";     
    include("dbinfo.php");   

    $file = checkUpload(); //the variable $file isn't been inserted with the rest of the form

    $sql="INSERT INTO cours VALUES(null, '$etablissement', '$classe', '$session', '$matiere', '$annee_scolaire', '$file', NOW())";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    //print <<<HERE

    echo "
        <h1>The following has been added:</h1>  
        <ul>     
        <li>Etablissement: $etablissement</li>   
        <li>Classe: $classe</li>     
        <li>Session: $session</li>   
        <li>Matiere: $matiere</li>
        <li>Annee scolaire: $annee_scolaire</li>     
        <li>Fichier:  $file </li>
        </ul>
        ";  

    //HERE;

}    

function printForm() //printing the form
{    
    //displays the html form     
    $pageTitle = "Add a Document";   
    //include("header.php");     

    //print <<<HERE  

    //<form id = "myForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    echo "
        <h2>Add a Document</h2> 

        <form id=myForm method=POST enctype=multipart/form-data>     

        <fieldset>
                                <legend>Formulaire d'enregistrement</legend>
                                <table class=formulaire_document_admin>     
                                <tr>
                         <td><label for=etablissement>Etablissement:</label></td><br />
                         <td><select class=alignement_etab name=etablissement id=etablissement tabindex=10>
                   <optgroup label=Lycee>
                                   <option value=>Selectionnez ici</option>
                       <option value=biyemassi>Lycee de Biyem-assi</option>
                       <option value=leclerc>Lycee General Leclerc</option>
                       <option value=techobala>Lycee Technique d'Obala</option>
                       <option value=etougebe>Lycee d'Etoug-ebe</option>
                                    <option value=efoulan>Lycee d'Efoulan</option>
                   </optgroup>
                   <optgroup label=College>
                       <option value=sagesse>College de la sagesse</option>
                       <option value=ebanda>College Ebanda</option>
                                   <option value=victorhugo>College vigtor hugo</option>
                                   <option value=mvolye>College St joseph de mvolye</option>
                                   <option value=rosiere>College de la rosiere</option>
                   </optgroup>
                           <optgroup label=Autres>
                                <option value=autre>Autres</option>
                           </optgroup>
                        </select></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                         <td><label for=matiere>Classe:</label></td><br />
                         <td><select class=alignement_classe name=classe id=classe tabindex=20>
                   <optgroup label=Général>
                               <option value=>Selectionnez ici</option>
                       <option value=sixieme>Sixième</option>
                       <option value=cinquieme>Cinquième</option>
                       <option value=quatrieme>Quatrième</option>
                       <option value=troisieme>Troisième</option>
                                   <option value=seconde>Seconde</option>
                                   <option value=premiere>Première</option>
                                   <option value=terminale>Terminale</option>
                   </optgroup>
                   <optgroup label=Technique>
                       <option value=annee1>Première année</option>
                                   <option value=annee2>Deuxième année</option>
                                   <option value=annee3>Troisième année</option>
                                   <option value=annee4>Quatrième année</option>
                                   <option value=annee5>Seconde technique</option>
                                   <option value=annee6>Première technique</option>
                       <option value=annee7>Terminale technique</option>
                   </optgroup>
                           <optgroup label=Autres>
                                <option value=autre>Autres</option>
                           </optgroup>
                        </select></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                         <td><label for=matiere>Session:</label></td><br />
                         <td><select class=alignementetabinscription1 name=session id=session tabindex=30>
                                   <option value=>Selectionnez ici</option>
                       <option value=examen_officiel>Examen Officiel</option>
                   <optgroup label=Mini session>
                       <option value=session1>1ère session</option>
                                   <option value=session2>2ème session</option>
                                   <option value=session3>3ème session</option>
                                   <option value=session4>4ème session</option>
                                   <option value=session5>5ème session</option>
                                   <option value=session6>6ème session</option>
                                   <option value=session7>7ème session</option>
                                   <option value=session8>8ème session</option>
                                   <option value=session9>9ème session</option>
                                   <option value=examen_blanc>Examen blanc</option>
                   </optgroup>
                        </select></td>
                                </tr>


                <tr>
                 <td><label for=matiere>Matière:</label></td><br />
                 <td><select class=alignement_matiere name=matiere id=matiere tabindex=50>
               <optgroup label=Scientifique>
                   <option value=>Selectionnez ici</option>
                   <option value=mathematique>Mathématiques</option>
                   <option value=physique>Physique</option>
                   <option value=chimie>Chimie</option>
                   <option value=biologie>Biologie</option>
                    <option value=informatique>Informatique</option>
               </optgroup>
               <optgroup label=Littéraire>
                   <option value=dictee>Dictée</option>
                   <option value=redaction>Rédaction</option>
                   <option value=etude_de_texte>Etude de texte</option>
                   <option value=litterature>Littérature</option>
                   <option value=dissertation>Dissertation</option>
                   <option value=philosophie>Philosophie</option>
                   <option value=anglais>Anglais</option>
                   <option value=espagnol>Espagnol</option>
                   <option value=allemand>Allemand</option>
                   <option value=histoire>Histoire</option>
                   <option value=geographie>Géographie</option>
                   <option value=ec>Education Civique</option>
               </optgroup>
               <optgroup label=Autres>
                <option value=autre>Autres</option>
               </optgroup>
                </select></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                 <td><label for=matiere>Année scolaire:</label></td><br />
                 <td><select class=alignementannee_sco name=anescolaire id=anescrolaire tabindex=50>
                   <option value=2005/2006>2005/2006</option>//different values given
                   <option value=2006/2007>2006/2007</option>
                   <option value=2007/2008>2007/2008</option>
                   <option value=2008/2009>2008/2009</option>
                   <option value=2009/2010>2009/2010</option>
                   <option value=2010/2011>2010/2011</option>
                   <option value=2011/2012>2011/2012</option>
                   <option value=2012/2013>2012/2013</option>
                   <option value=2013/2014>2013/2014</option>
                </select></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <p>
                <td><label for=nom>Epreuve:</label></td>
                <td><input type=file name=epreuve id=epreuve size=50 value= tabindex=60 class=alignement_epreuve/></td>
                <br/><small>Must be less than 1Mo. Only pdf, doc, docx, ppt or pptx documents allowed. </small>
                </p>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </fieldset>
                <tr>
                <div id=mySubmit>
                    <p>
                    <td><input type=submit name=submit value=Submit> <input type=reset value=Cancel></td>
                    </p>
                </div>
                </tr>   

    </form> ";


    //HERE;  

}
?>
```

Comment: You should try to figure out where is the problem in your code. Not post million lines of it.

Comment: Your `cleanData` function does not prevent SQL injections. Have a look at [how to prevent them properly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: What Gers printed ? We cannot huées the problem AND the solution

Answer (score 0):

In `checkUpload`, `return $file` is in the wrong place. It's in the `else` block, so it only gets executed when the file type is invalid. Also, if the function detects an error, it needs to exit, since there's no file to return to the caller.

```
function checkUpload() //check whether everything is OK before uploading the file
{
    //check for an uploaded file
    if(isset($_FILES['epreuve'])){
        //Validate the type 

        $allowed_extensions = array('application/pdf','application/pdf','application/doc','application/docx','application/ppt','application/pptx');
        if(in_array($_FILES['epreuve']['type'], $allowed_extensions)){
            print "Uploading files...";

            //move the file over
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['epreuve']['tmp_name'], "../../assnet/uploads/{$_FILES['epreuve']['name']}")){
                echo "<p><em>The file has been uploaded</em></p>";

                $file = "{$_FILES['epreuve']['name']}";
                print "$file"; //the file name is normally displayed here
            } //End of move... IF
        } else{ //invalid type
            echo '<p class="error">Please upload a pdf, doc, docx, ppt or pptx document</p>';
            exit;
        }
        if($_FILES['epreuve']['error'] > 0){
            echo '<p class="error">The file could not be uploaded because : </strong>';
            //Print a message upon the error. NB: There is no error message 5

            switch($_FILES['epreuve']['error']){
            case 1:
                print 'The file exceeds the upload_max_file_size setting in php.ini.';
                break;
            case 2:
                print 'The file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE setting in the HTML form';
                break;
            case 3:
                print 'The file was only partially uploaded';
                break;
            case 4:
                print 'No file was uploaded';
                break;
            case 6:
                print 'No temporary folder was available';
                break;
            case 7:
                print 'Unable to write to disk';
                break;
            case 8: 
                print 'File upload stopped';
                break;
            default:
                print 'A system error occured';
                break;
            } //End of switch
            exit;
        }//End of Error... IF

        //Delete the file if it still exists
        if(file_exists($_FILES['epreuve']['tmp_name']) && is_file($_FILES['epreuve']['tmp_name'])){
            print 'File already exists';
            unlink($_FILES['epreuve']['tmp_name']); //delete the file from the temporary folder if it still exists
        }   
        return $file; //returns the file from where it comes from
        //i.e from the addData function "[$image=checkUpload()]"

    }
}
```